# When to use 'Set a Default org' option in VS Code Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

Can anyone please help me to understand what is the purpose of "Set a Default Org" command in VS Code? Is it like if I change my default org to some other org, all the subsequent code deployments will happen to that new default org and if we Retrieve something from manifest file will it be from the new Default org?

I am not understanding the part where documentation says : `Sets the configuration variables that the Salesforce CLI uses for various commands and tasks. Local variables apply only to your current project. Global variables apply in any directory.`

Can anyone please help me to understand how this 'Set Default Org' works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly right. The VS Code Extension Bundle does not ask for which org you want to deploy/retrieve to/from. You need to set a default org in order to use many of the commands in the bundle. This also sets the config files so that the CLI (e.g. bash) will also automatically deploy/retrieve to/from that org. Setting it locally affects only the current workspace, while setting it globally affects all workspaces. You can see the currently selected default org in the lower-left corner on the status bar in VS Code, and the CLI can show you the currently selected org via `sfdx force:config:list`.

Comment: Okay Got it. Then, what is the difference between 'SFDX: Authorize an Org' v/s 'SFDX: Set Default Org' ? If we authorize an org then also, the lower left shows that Org Alias and Deployments also happens with that Authorized Org and if 'SFDX: Set Default Org' also does the same then what could be the difference between the two?

Comment: @sfdc07 Authorize an Org adds a *new* org to the list of sessions you have available. Set Default Org sets an *already existing* org as the default from the list of sessions you have available.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much..!!

Comment: I'm confused - when I run `sfdx force:config:list` I get a Name/Value/Location of "defaultusername"/"vscodeOrg"/"Local"...but I'm successfully deploying to my own sandbox - so why is the default org listed as "vscodeOrg"? I'm missing something.

Comment: @jbyrd You called the alias `vscodeOrg`. It's just a reference to the logged in user, though (your sandbox org, presumably).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the org you specify with "Set a Default Org" is the one SDFX (and therefore VS Code) connects to by default for the purposes of metadata deployment, retrieval, test runs, etc.

When you select "SFDX: Set a Default Org" from the Command Palette in VS Code (Ctrl + Shift + P), the following Salesforce CLI command is run (and you can see this in the output):

`sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=MY_ORG_ALIAS`

Per [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_config.htm#cli_reference_force_config) for this command, this will apply locally within the project you have open, since it doesn't use the `-g`/`--global` flag. You can alternate between using the Salesforce Extensions for VS Code and running `sfdx` or `sf` commands in the terminal, and the same default will apply.

To confirm which environment you're defaulted to, look for the alias next to the electrical plug icon in VS Code's Status Bar:

[image: Default Org showing in VS Code Status Bar]

Or run any of the following commands in the terminal:

```
$ sf config get target-org
$ sfdx config:get defaultusername
```

Comment: Okay, then same can be done using 'SFDX: Authorize and Org' also right? So, what could be the difference between 'SFDX: Set Default Org' v/s 'SFDX : Authorize an org'?

Comment: Once you've authorized an org once, you can use "SFDX: Set Default Org" to switch orgs without having to provide your credentials again.  Typically I only use "SFDX: Authorize an Org" when setting up a new org connection, or after a password change or sandbox refresh.

Answer (score 2):

In the Salesforce CLI v2, you can use this command to set your default org:

```
sf config set target-org my-scratch-org
```

Answer (score 1):

*Another option to set default org and authorize an org in single command.*
When you have successfully authorize an org to the Vs code then to get the deploy/ retrieve options in your code, You have to set the default org for that project because vs code does not know on which org you want to deploy, So need to set default org.

You can set default org by following these simple steps

Apart from this set default username command

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=<Alias_name>

        ---------- OR ----------
```

You can also **set the default username at the time of login** through terminal command by using the below command

> sfdx auth:web:login --setalias <Alias_name> --instanceurl
> <YourOrgURL/InstanceURL>